# Subclass UIScrollView in Swift for touches Began & touches Moved

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, touchesbegan

[image]I'm using Swift 1.2

I'm trying to use this [UIScrollview touchesbegan,touchesmoved,touchesended actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660327/uiscrollview-touchesbegan-touchesmoved-touchesended-actions) and the link in the 2nd comment of the accepted answer.

I'm using a storyboard with auto layout, I set my custom class for the UIScrollView in Custom Class.

I'm not receiving either of these touch events in the UIViewController that contains my custom UIScrollView

**Edit: Updated my code for how I use it with @Victor Sigler 's answer.**

Custom ScrollView Code:

```
import UIKit

protocol PassTouchesScrollViewDelegate {

func scrollTouchBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent)
func scrollTouchMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent)
}

class PassTouchesScrollView: UIScrollView {

var delegatePass : PassTouchesScrollViewDelegate?

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    self.delegatePass?.scrollTouchBegan(touches, withEvent: event)


}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    self.delegatePass?.scrollTouchMoved(touches, withEvent: event)

}

}
```

My ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, PassTouchesScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scrollView.delegatePass = self
}

func scrollTouchBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent)    {

    println("began \(touches)")

}

func scrollTouchMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent)      {

    println("moved \(touches)")
}     

}
```

I'm trying to let a user draw a line over a UIImage, which I got working using a PanGesture Recognizer but the performance was very poor, especially on older hardware, I followed a Ray Wenderlich tutorial that used touches Began and the performance was much better, however it was on a UIView and not a ScrollView. I need a UIScrollView since prior to a user drawing on an image they can zoom in and around it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're thinking about this wrong. If you want to know when a `UIScrollView` is moving, there's no need to subclass it. iOS has set up all the methods you need inside of the `UIScrollViewDelegate`.

You must implement the [`UISCrollViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/) to be notified about the actions in the `UIScrollView` and set the `delegate` by Interface Builder or in code, is up to you.

See the following example to know how to do it for example :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

     @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       self.scrollView.delegate = self
     }
}
```

Still if you want to know how its touched in the way you explained above you must follow the following steps :

1. You must subclass from the `UIScrollView` class as you did in your class `PassTouchesScrollView` and implement the delegate pattern to be notified about the `UIScrollView` in the following way:

   ```
   import UIKit

   protocol PassTouchesScrollViewDelegate {
      func touchBegan()
      func touchMoved()
   }


   class PassTouchesScrollView: UIScrollView {

     var delegatePass : PassTouchesScrollViewDelegate?

     override init(frame: CGRect) {
       super.init(frame: frame)
     }

     required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
     }

     override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        // Notify it's delegate about touched
        self.delegatePass?.touchBegan()

       if self.dragging == true {
          self.nextResponder()?.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
       } else {
          super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
       }

    }

     override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent)  {

        // Notify it's delegate about touched
        self.delegatePass?.touchMoved()

        if self.dragging == true {            
           self.nextResponder()?.touchesMoved(touches, withEvent: event)
        } else {            
          super.touchesMoved(touches, withEvent: event)
        }
     }   
   }
   ```
2. Your class `ViewController` must be implemented in the following way:

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

     @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: PassTouchesScrollView!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()        
       scrollView.delegate = self  
       scrollView.delegatePass = self      
     }

     override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
     }

     func touchMoved() {
        println("touch moved")
     }

     func touchBegan() {
        println("touch began")
     }

   }
   ```
3. You must be in the Interface Builder select your `UIScrollView` and set the class for it as your class `PassTouchesScrollView`, in the Identity Inspector in the class part.

And you should see in your console the following:

```
touch began
touch began
touch began
touch began
touch began
touch began
touch moved
touch move
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: I don't want to know when it's moving, I want to know when it's being touched which sadly the delegate methods don't provide for, At the point in time where a user does touch the scroll view it's scrollEnabled property is set to false (to ensure proper scaling).

Comment: I don't know why but this isn't working for me, this is what I do have.

Comment: @thefredelement you have set the class for the `UIScrollView` in the Interface Builder?? It's very important

Comment: I going to share it a project in Github with the explained above. I going to send you the link you to see it.

Comment: @thefredelement See my sample project in [Github](https://github.com/Vkt0r/ScrollViewTouchTest)

Comment: that project doesn't work either, I bet you think it's working because there's no constraints on the UIScrollView and it's just taking up a small amount of space in the upper left of the window.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75946/discussion-between-victor-sigler-and-thefredelement).

Comment: After testing for hours I know the solution: You forgot to link "PassTouchesScrollViewDelegate" in the ViewController. So it should be: "class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate, PassTouchesScrollViewDelegate {"

Answer (score 8):

try this

```
  extension UIScrollView {

    override open func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.next?.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        print("touchesBegan")
    }

    override open func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.next?.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
        print("touchesMoved")
    }

    override open func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.next?.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        print("touchesEnded")
    }

}
```

Comment: like this https://github.com/Ryosuke-Hujisawa/How-to-call-touchesmovedwp-in-uiscrollview-Swift-3

Answer (score 0):

`touchesBegan` only works on a subclass of `UIView`. Take it out of your UIViewController to make it work.

[UIResponder Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html)

Comment: I'm confused by this answer, touchesBegan & touchesMoved are called when I touch an area on the screen outside of the UIScrollView, do you mean I should put the UIScrollView inside of a UIView?

Comment: I am saying the delegate methods touchesBegan should only fire inside of a UIView subclass. Placing them in a UIViewController should not fire the methods. So yes, if you place those methods in the UIScrollView that would also work. Just not in a controller.

Comment: The UIViewController does contain it's own UIView that's why it responds when I touch the screen outside of the UIScrollView (it's frame is 600x200), and in the custom subclass of the UIScrollView I'm trying to pass the touch events that I put in there up to that UIViewController's view by using super.touchesBegan and super.touchesMoved

Comment: The UIViewController does contain it's own UIView that's why it responds when I touch the screen outside of the UIScrollView (it's size is 600x400), and in the custom subclass of the UIScrollView I'm trying to pass the touch events that I put in there up to that UIViewController's view by using super.touchesBegan and super.touchesMoved. I added a screen shot to my question. When I touch the white area above and below the UIScrollView I get my println output on both touchesBegan and touchesMoved.